# Is there a way to do python's kwargs passthrough in ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

So I have some functions in Ruby 1.9 where it would be really, really nice to do the functional equivalent of this:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    ...do stuff...

def bar(**kwargs):
    foo(x = 2, y = 3, **kwargs)
```

So Ruby has opts, but if I do this:

```
def f(opts)
    print opts.keys
end

def g(opts)
    f(opts, :bar=>3)
end

g(:foo => 1)
```

I get:

`script:1:in f': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from script:6:in g'
    from script:9:in <main>'`

Is there a way to pass opts through from g into f?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
def g(opts)
    f(opts, :bar=>3)
end
```

passes two arguments to `f`. To let is pass one, do this:

```
def g(opts)
    f(opts.merge(:bar=>3))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Like below?

```
def f(opts)
    print opts.keys
end

def g(opts)
    opts[:bar] = 3
    f(opts)
end

g(:foo => 1)
```